# How to create a symbol table if given a grammar in a yacc file?

Tags: yacc

I'm given a yacc file and I'm supposed to create a symbol table.  What do I do after I use yacc on the file?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad, and there exist books and online resources to answer it.
It would be best for you to do some reading and then come back and ask more targeted questions.

Check out the answers to this StackOverflow question for links to Yacc tutorials:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641701/excellent-online-tutorial-for-lex-and-yacc